# Nginx Proxy Manager (Docker) + mail server

Tags: linux, docker

im having a server running ubuntu with docker.

I have a docker instance running Nginx Proxy Manager to serve my multiple domains.

I want to run a mail server but since Nginx is using port 443 for HTTPS and 80 for HTTP i cant install any docker image's since they make use of both 80 and 443.

Example https://poste.io/doc/getting-started#download its also make use of the same ports.

Any idea how to have a single IP and host both web and mail?